# Nondeterministic Communication Complexity - How to Calculate it from Communication Matrix?

Tags: complexity-theory, communication-complexity

I have been wracking my head around the understanding on how to calculate $N_{1}(f)$ and $N_{0}(f)$ from the communication matrix.

**Definitions:**
$N_{1}(f)$ = least cost of non-deterministic protocol that accepts $f^{-1}(1) = \{(x,y) : f(x,y) = 1 \}$

$N_{1}(f)$ = ceiling( log(number of monochromatic rectangles needed to cover $f^{-1}(1)$))

**Examples:**
I would like to connect understand how this gets translated into the following two examples:

*Equality*
We know that the communication matrix has 1s on the diagonal and everything else is covered with 0.
$N_{1}(f) = n$ - this makes sense, I need exactly $n$ rectangles to cover my 1s on the diagonal, one rectangle per cell.
$N_{0}(f) = \log n + 1$ - this does *not* make sense. How can you cover all 0s with only that many monochromatic rectangles?

*Greater Than*
We know that the communication matrix has 1s on the diagonal and on top of it and everything else is covered with 0s.
$N_{1}(f) = n$ - I am assuming the rectangles are now not just an individual cell in the diagonal, but the whole row. 
$N_{0}(f) = n$ - I am assuming the rectangles are now the entire column.

If my understanding for $N_{0}(f)$ for the *Greater Than* is correct, then I do not understand how the colouring works for the *Equality* problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the $\log n + 1$ rectanges that cover all 0s in the case of the Equality function: for all $i \in [\log n]$ and $b \in \{0, 1\}$, there is a rectangle
$$
 \{ (x,y) : x_i = b, y_i \neq b \} = \{ x : x_i = b \} \times \{y : y_i \neq b \} .
$$

Comment: But the number of such rectangles is still greater than than the rectangles on diagonal... It is impossible to colour all 0s in less than n-1 where n is the number of entries on each axis.

Comment: There are $n$ rectangles on the diagonal, an exponentially larger number.

Comment: I agree. The way I colour my 0s is the following. For each row I can put all 0s left and all 0s right of the diagonal (the only cell that contains 1 in that given row) in one rectangle. Which means, in total I will have 2*(n-1) + 2 rectangles

Comment: For the sake of nondeterministic complexity we need a cover, not a partition.

Comment: You asked "How can you cover all 0s with only that many rectangles?" This answer explains how. Coloring is not mentioned in your post at all.

Comment: Fair point, I should have rephrased it that I would like to use only monochromatic rectangles

Comment: The rectangle in this answer are monochromatic.

Comment: Apologies, but I understand the monochromatic rectangles as a way of colouring the matrix. If I am understanding incorrectly, could you explain or point me to some resources?

Comment: A deterministic protocol is a partition of the communication matrix into monochromatic rectangles. (This is perhaps where you got the idea of coloring.) A non-deterministic protocol is a covering of the 1-s of the communication matrix by 1-monochromatic rectangles. The covering need not be a partition. If a point is covered by $k$ rectangles, this means that it has $k$ witness, which is ok as long as $k \ge 1$.

Comment: I now agree with the proof - we are using combinatorial rectangles and they do not need to be composed of cells that are direct neighbours to each other.